# Unable to install grunt-contrib-testem using npm

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to install the node package 'grunt-contrib-testem' and getting the following error. Is this package no longer supported ??

```
npm install grunt-contrib-testem --save-dev
npm WARN package.json testproject@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json testproject@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json testproject@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/Users/user1/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-contrib-testem" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-testem
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'grunt-contrib-testem' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'testproject'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

If this is no longer supported in registry.npmjs.org, i think i have to get the tar ball and install it.

From my browser i can access the URL http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-testem !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They changed the name of this package to grunt-testem-mincer, I had the same surprise as you.